# Replacing fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

My application, has a navigation drawer and also sliding tabs.

Problem : I have implemented sliding tabs in the main activity, onclick of the navigation drawer items opens differnent fragment and it works fine, but it hides inside the sliding tabs which i implemented in the main activity,

My Aim : I want the default page to be sliding tabs, and if i click navigation icons , the sliding tabs page must close and opens the content in the fragment which i have implemented for navigation icons.

Code as follows.

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    <tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="keleno.example.ramz.mapper_city.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[] = {"CITY", "GO", "NEAR"};
int Numboftabs = 3;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);


    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);


    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view,  final int position) {
displayView(position);

}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ContactFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_contact);

            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MyLocation();

            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_myloc);
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new TermsandCondition();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_terms);
            break;

        case 3:
            fragment = new UpgradePlan();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_upgrade);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Aboutus();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_about);


            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        //   fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out,android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        // actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>ActionBartitle </font>"));
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>" + title + " </font>"));
        //  final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        //  upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        // getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need a good sample code for Sliding Tabs. If I have a chance, I will provide a link.

Comment: could you provide me the link

Comment: do you want  sliding tabs only under one particular fragment,right?

Comment: yes. I want to display sliding tap in only one fragment

Comment: you could just move tab layout code inside the fragment..no need to keep it inside mainactivity layout file..Because you only keep those things in mainactivity file which are common across fragments.. see my answer below for more details

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your sliding tabs as a fragment so that it can be replaced by other fragments instead of making a slidingtab activity

Answer (score 0):

As said you want to show only the tabs in one fragment then you should remove the tab inside main layout and use it inside the fragment layout directly..

Just keep

**drawerlayout > 
toolbar > fragment[your fragment which would contain tabs inflated using fragment.xml] > navigationview** in mainactivity layout file

Move your tab xml code inside other fragment.xml file

Comment: Thanks, actually if the application starts running it should by default show sliding tab layout(in my case it is the main activity), then if i click one of the navigation drawer items, it should show that particular fragment and not main activity. This  s working, but main activity overlaps the content of the fragment.

Comment: That's what i am saying populate your main activity but don't include tablayout in mainactivity.xml file..but just keep bare minimum layout like toolbar + navigation drawer + fragment(whose content would be displayed by fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good webpage from Google @ [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) and I have used it. I believe it will satisfy your requirements of having **sliding** multiple **tabs** as the main UI. The MainActivity extends from FragmentActivity as the child class. Another words, MainActivity could be a Fragment instead but I don't recommend you make the sample project more complicated, keep it simple for a start.